# TypeScript - returning 2 different interface from a function

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering how can I returning 2 types of object according their interface.

Into the code below, the declared return of my function

```
: Promise<newEventInt | newWalletInt>
```

make both value that I return underlined

```
return {
        currentEvent, 
        wallet
    }
```

the error message for currentEvent, is that one

```
Type 'newEventInt' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Date | undefined'.
  Type 'newEventInt' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

If I take off the declared return, it is working. But I would like to give my code more protection.

thanks in advance,
Paul

```
    private async isEventOwnedByUser(userId: number, eventId: number): Promise<newEventInt | newWalletInt> {
        // get event + handling error
        const currentEvent: newEventInt = await this.event.findOne(eventId)            
        if (!currentEvent) throw new Error(`This event does not exist`);

        //  get user's wallet + handling error
        const wallet: newWalletInt = await this.wallet.getOneWalletByUserId(currentEvent.wallet_id, userId)   
        if (!wallet) throw new Error('This event does not exist')

        return {
            currentEvent, 
            wallet
        }
    }
```

the newEventInt interface

```
export interface newEventInt {
    [key: string]: number | string | Date;

    type: string,
    date: Date,
    quantity: number,
    total_amount: number,
    unit_price: number,
    fees: number,
    note: string,
    platform_sending: string,
    platform_receiving: string,
    currency_asset: string,
    currency_counterparty: string,
    currency_fees: number,
    wallet_id: number,
    ref_usd_amount: number,
    ref_usd_fees: number,
    created_at: Date
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Promise<newEventInt | newWalletInt>` be `Promise<{ currentEvent: newEventInt, wallet: newWalletInt }>`? You're not returning a union, you're returning *both* as two keys of one object. However, I don't really understand the error message - unless I'm missing something, seems like it shouldn't be coming from this code.

Comment: Hey VLAZ, thanks for your response, unfortunately it is not working as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the meaning of `newEventInt | newWalletInt`. This is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types), which allows either a `newEventInt` or a `newWalletInt` to be returned.

However your function returns something else: an object with two properties, one of each type. This object implements this interface:

```
interface EventAndWallet {
  currentEvent: newEventInt
  wallet: newWalletInt
}
```

So if you define that interface and change the return type of your function to `Promise<EventAndWallet>` your error should go away.